# "At Amararaja Batteries Limited" vs. "in Amararaja Batteries Limited"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, at-in

> 1. I have done my internship **at** Amararaja Batteries Limited.
> 2. I have done my internship **in** Amararaja Batteries Limited.

Which of the above sentences is correct? I want to know when to use *at* and when to use *in*.

Comment: Probably _at_. _In_ refers to a container, and unless you want to say you're still inside, you should refer to a company as a place, not your residence.

Answer (score 0):

Choice (1) is more suitable than (2).  Follow *internship **at*** with a company, organization, hospital, or university name; follow *internship **in*** with the name of a field of study or the name of a city, state, or country; and follow *internship **with*** with an individual's name, or sometimes an organization or company.  There are exceptions, but I think the above suggestions are appropriate for many cases.